# Proving that $D_{10}/ N$ is isomorphic to $D_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Question:** $N:=\lbrace 1,x^5 \rbrace$. Show that the quotient group $D_{10}/N$ is isomorphic to $D_5$.

I was looking over the proof for this and quite frankly I didn't really understand it very well. [The proof can be found here](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/hs2013/math/algebra1/Solution5.pdf) and it's question 2, the last part of the question. I understand that they're using a theorem that states that if a function is a homomorphism, then it preserves unity, inverses and powers. But I'm not entirely sure how that proves that $D_{10}/N$ is isomorphic to $D_5$. Also, their conclusion doesn't make much sense to me.

What other approaches can we take to prove this claim?

Comment: Note that $D_{10}$ here is the dihedral group of order $20$, and $x$ is an element of order $10$.

Answer (score 1):

This may be slightly nonrigorous, but we can think of this simply geometrically and recalling that when we mod out by $N$ we are equating objects that differ only by the objects in $N$. Now, going by the comment by @MJD, we are dealing with a regular 20-gon in the plane. The dihedral group is then made of rotations and reflections. The object $x^5$ is a rotation amplified by a factor of 5 or a 5-fold reflection across a fixed axis, i.e. a single reflection, depending on which element we take to be $x$. So we need only care about the rotations. It shouldn't be too hard to convince yourself that the rotations and reflections in this new space are equivalent to rotations and reflections of the 10-gon, and that will let us construct the needed isomorphism